# MIPS printing out an address instead of the value at that address

Tags: assembly, mips32

So I've written code that takes in a string from the user which is in the format where the first character is a non numeric one and the rest are numbers. My code removes the first character and stores the remaining numbers in a variable. Now I'm attempting to add a constant (example 5) to the remaining numbers and print them out. I'm unsure whats going wrong.

```
.data

    string: .asciiz      "Enter a string:\n"
    string1: .asciiz         "The value +5 is:\n"
    inputString: .space 20
    outInt: .word 0
    int5: .word 5
    addedInt: .word 0


.text

main:

    #print initial string to console insruction 4
    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, string
    syscall

    #get first string from user
    li  $v0, 8
    la  $a0, inputString
    li  $a1, 8      #a1 contains max length of string to be entered
    la  $t0, ($a0)
    syscall

    addiu   $t0, $t0, 1 #remove first letter

    li  $v0, 4      #prints out remaining numbers without leading character
    la  $a0, ($t0)
    syscall

    sw  $a0, outInt #store new word in outInt 


    lw  $t0, outInt #print out outInt to check if its correct
    la  $a0, ($t0)
    syscall

    lw  $t1, int5
    add $t2, $t0, $t1   #add 5 to the remaining numbers

    sw  $t2, addedInt   #store result
    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, string1    #print the value + 5 string
    syscall

    li  $v0, 1  #output a number (not a string)
    lw  $a0,  addedInt


    syscall

    jr $ra
```

The output when I enter the string "X123" is:

Enter a string:

X123

123

123

The value +5 is:

268501033

Comment: What *should* the output be, and why?

Comment: The output should be 128 (because 123 + 5 = 128). Its for an assignment.

Comment: What do you see in registers when you use the debugger to single-step your code?

Answer (score 1):

What your code does:

Inputs string into 20 byte memory buffer at address `inputString` (which happens to be `268501027` under MARS, which looks exactly same allocation like you get during your run).

If the user enters "X123", then the bytes in memory look like this: `58 31 32 33 0A 00 00 00 ...` (didn't find out, how to display memory per byte in MARS, so you have to understand how little-endian works, and how those word values displayed in MARS can be break down to particular single bytes), 0x58 is ASCII code for letter X, 0x31 is ASCII code for letter/digit 1, etc... 0x0A is newline character (part of input!), the remaining zeroes are your luck, that MARS provides you with zeroed .data segment at the beginning of run of code, so your next output of user string is correctly zero-terminated (and does do also newline).

Then you output string from address `inputString+1`, which points to that `0x31` = ASCII code for digit `'1'`, and the remaining of user input follows, thus the expected (?) string "123\n" is outputted. Note the "remove first letter" doesn't remove anything from the machine, just adjusts the pointer, which is then used as "start" of string. Truly removing the letter in the same memory space would require you to copy byte by byte all the letter to previous address, which is much more costly operation, then adjusting single pointer by one.

```
sw  $a0, outInt      #store new word in outInt
```

This stores that adjusted address `268501028` into memory word at address `outInt`. It doesn't store the word itself. Nor any conversion of string to int happens here. All you do is just store the pointer (memory address), which is 32b unsigned integer 268501028.

Then you call next `syscall` without explicitly stating `v0` argument, so the previous value `4` is re-used, to output string again, from the same address, so again you get the same output `"123\n"`. I would recommend to always set explicitly the `v0` ahead of every `syscall`, even if it's the same value which is already in register, makes for easier reading of the source when debugging in head and reviewing.

Finally you load value 5 into `t1`, and add that to that address `268501028` which results into integer `268501033`, and store that into memory at address `addedInt`. Then you print out the +5 label, and load that value back into `a0`, and print it out.

You should use the built-in debugger of MARS/SPIM-family simulator you use, to single step over instructions, and watch the register values + memory content, comparing it to my description, to fully grasp what those instructions actually do.

fix:

"too broad", basically you need either:

a) to convert the user string into integer value: loading letter by letter the input until you reach either newline character or zero terminator, converting digit letters into values `(ASCII_code - '0') == digit_value`, then calculating temporary sum, as `sum = sum*10 + digit_value`, starting with `sum = 0`. At the end of the loop the `sum` will contain value `123` (from the string `"123"`). Then you can add `5` as integer (getting value `128`), and use `syscall, v0=1` to output it.

b) do the adding of value 5 over string, i.e. finding the address of newline/zero-terminator, then going back by 1 you have address of last digit (if input is valid! You may want to validate by comparing to address `inputString`, and if address is valid, you may also check content to be within range `'0' = 0x30`..`'9' = 0x39`, i.e. that the content is ASCII digit-letter. Then loop: 1) add 5 to current letter 2) if result is `<= '9'`, then string looks like number, and you can output  it (branch to output with `inputString+1` address to display). 3) subtract 10 from it (i.e. `'7'+5 = 60 = '<'`, then `60 - 10 = 50 = digit-letter '2'`) 4) decrement the address by 1 (moving one position left) 5) validate address. 6) check content: if not digit, overwrite it with letter `'1'` and jump to output from address of that `'1'` (with valid input like `"X99"` that will be equal to `inputString`, and the memory will contain modified string `"104"`), if digit, add one to it and jump to step 2) - checking if the resulting value was `<= '9'`.

And that's it, that's "adding 5" when you don't operate over integer values, but over ASCII letters in memory. May sound like lot of work, but it may be actually simpler to write + debug than the conversion string-to-int in variant a).

Ultimately you should probably try to write both variants, just to better understand how basic data types in assembly works, and what's the difference between "strings" and integer values (and byte and word values), and how memory addressing works.

Answer (score 1):

```
    sw  $t2, addedInt   #store result
    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, string1    #print the value + 5 string
    syscall
```

You're loading the ADDRESS of string1 with `la`.  You should load the word itself with `lw` to print the string itself.  I didn't look at what you're doing to the string, but I just did this in my own project.

hth